# получеловеческий-полуживотный

Tags: орфография

Какое из этих написаний будет правильным?

получеловеческое-полуживотное тело

полу-человеческое, полу-животное тело

получеловеческое, полуживотное тело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: получеловеческое-полуживотное тело.

Из Правил Лопатина, § 118. 
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=64#pp64

Парные конструкции, состоящие из слов с первой частью полу-, напр.: полугород-полудеревня, полунемец-полурусский, полусказка-полубыль, полусон-полуявь; полувоенный-полугражданский, полунасмешливый-полусочувствующий, полушутя-полусерьёзно, полулёжа-полусидя.